# Link back to Google from API Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API v3 to generate some minimaps. I have one custom marker in a small map with controls hidden. This works great. Now, I'd like to add a link so that clicking this marker will open the full Google Maps with this location selected. Seems obvious.

I'm creating a marker like this.

```
var pin = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: pin,
   map: map,
   title:"Hello World"
});
```

This seems like it should be obvious, what am I missing? Do I need to construct my link and assign it myself?

Comment: Add a click event handler to the marker to open the full map.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (not tested):

```
var pin = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: pin,
   map: map,
   title:"Hello World"
});
google.maps.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   window.location = "https://maps.google.com/maps?ll="+pin.toUrlValue;
});
```

[Working example (built on an existing example, not from the above code)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_redirectOnClick.html)

Comment: Ah - I did make a couple of changes but your help led me to the solution. Will post below...

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding the answer thusly:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.open("https://maps.google.com/maps?ll="+pin.toUrlValue(),'_blank');
});
```